How to customize the system-wide vimrc file in MacOS Sonoma?
I would like to set some options in the system-wide vimrc file so that they are available to all users of the system. Initially I tried simply sourcing another file from the system-wide /usr/share/vim/vimrc, but this didn't work as the file is apparently read-only (restricted):
$ ls -lO /usr/share/vim/vimrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 557 Oct 15 14:22 /usr/share/vim/vimrc

How do I go about customizing global options for the default Vim install then?

Ignore the system vim and build a new one.  Set where you want it to keep its config files.  Done.

According to the vim(1) man page, the system-wide initialization files are read from /usr/local/lib/vim. Copy the read-only file there and make whatever changes you want.

The output of vim --version contradicts that (which is odd, btw). Anyway, I tried that as well and it didn't work.

The output of that command includes this: system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc", and also fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim". So apparently the man page is wrong, but you should be able to fix it by exporting a suitable value for VIM in your system-wide shell initialization file(s).
